# Using value in deleted record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to delete record and search by its Id in anther query as this

```
select * from Flat
WHERE  Flat.nu in (delete top (1) from temp output deleted.nu)
```

Comment: Why do you need that? -when you can use triggers and Cascade Delete- ;).

Comment: If you just want to find invalid FKs, just use a `LEFT JOIN` and filter `null` results ;).

Comment: shA.t it's part of a large query

Comment: select * from Flat inner join (delete top (1) from  dbo.temp output deleted.nu) del on  flat.nu=del.nu

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't run those with each other.

I suggest you to use a (temporary table): `tempIds(id int)`.
Then use `output` clause like this:

```
delete top(1) from temp
output deleted.id into tempIds;
```

Note: It's better to use CTE to delete first row.

Then query over `tempIds` table and after that clear `tempIds`.

Comment: Best make that intermediate table a temporary table.

Comment: @TT. [Both are suggested](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2005/06/13/output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/) ;).

Comment: Mkay, I'm not a big fan of using a regular table for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.. it may help you out.

```
DECLARE @ID_CAPTURE TABLE (ID Int)
DELETE TOP(1) FROM TEMP
OUTPUT deleted.Nu into @ID_CAPTURE

SELECT * FROM FLAT WHERE NU IN (SELECT * FROM @ID_CAPTURE)
```

The above snippet will work for you in case of multiple records too.